# plivo delivery report in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, plivo

I am using plivo in .net technology

and try go get the sms delivery report in a proper arranged way but I am not getting this as per the code shown in demo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using RestSharp;
using Plivo.API;
using Nancy;

namespace plivoNetApplication
{
    public class deliver_report : NancyModule
    {
        public void Program()
        {
            Post["/delivery_report"] = x =>
            {
                String from_number = Request.Form["From"]; // Sender's phone number
                String to_number = Request.Form["To"]; // Receiver's phone number
                String status = Request.Form["Status"]; // Status of the message
                String uuid = Request.Form["MessageUUID"]; // Message UUID

                 string message = "From" + from_number + "To" + to_number + "Status" + status + "UUID" + uuid;

                 return message;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Is your code hosted on the internet and publically available? You could use something like https://appharbor.com/ to achieve this.  When sending a message, have you set the `url` parameter to the url associated with this code snippet?